# what does exclamation mark before the boolean?

Tags: java

```
if(!checkSecondNum())
```

Where checkSecondNum is a method of boolean return type and why we used exclamatory sign in if statement please describe me in brief.

Comment: (!(A Good Question)) == Not A Good Question.

Answer (score 3):

`!`  called as [**boolean negation  or Logical compliment**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) and  makes  just inverts the result.

If your method `checkSecondNum()`  returns `false`  then

```
if(!checkSecondNum())
```

Becomes `true`.

`!false`  equals to `true`

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the summary of Java operators:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

In this specific case, `!` is a logical `NOT`.

Answer (score 0):

`!` is logical not operator.
That means when `checkSecondNum()` returns `false` execution will enter the if block.

`!false = true` and
  `!true = false`

Answer (score 0):

I think your progarm just wants to do the thing that when `checkSecondNum()` is not true, then executes the code in `if{}`. So your should use a `!`.

Answer (score 0):

- ! is Logical NOT operator.
- It will work reverse with your condition.
  See simple example Given Below. 
  example-

  ```
   n1=!true  // it returns false

  n2=!false  // it returns true 

  n3=!"Cat"  // it returns false
  ```
- Hope you got meaning of NOT operator.Same in your case.